# Статик или обьект- как правильнее?

Tags: php, ооп

Вот задался таким вопросом, где и как лучше использовать статик методы?.. 
Читал про них, но так и не понял где лучше использовать их, в каких ситуациях..

На пример, есть класс для работы с базой, и у класса есть метод query

```
$db = new Db();
$db->query($sql);
```

Если здесь использовать не объект класса, а статистический метод сделать, как лучше?

По удобству мне лучше статик использовать, но как правильно использовать, и не хуже ли будет...?

```
Db::query($sql);
```

Comment: статический метод - метод не привязанный к экземпляру объекта, представьте метод возвращающий одинаковый ответ от класса либо экземпляра, то есть не привязан к данным экземпляра, так смысл добавлять его в экземпляр?

Comment: То есть, если метод не использует аттрибуты своего класса то можно смело его использовать?.. Я думал есть какая-то связь с статическими свойствами, типо что нельзя использовать выражение (до 5.6  но и там ограничения)ъ

Comment: а не проще не думать, а попробовать, я уже молчу о прочтении документации или книги для чайников.

Comment: Читаю материал на разных сайтах ,и использую. Работает все, но задумался правильно л

Comment: Static method = function + namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш пример с DB неполный поэтому вы и засомневались. Ключевой момент здесь это то, откуда вы будете брать параметры подключения к базе. Если они у вас зашиты в класс это неверно. Если они вынесены в кофиг это лучше, и логика обращения к конфигу и получения параметров внутри вашего класса Db есть, но нужно подумать о ситуации когда у вас будет несколько подключений, тогда либо передавать идентификатор подключения по которому будут получатся параметры из конфига. Но это делает ваш класс зависимым от этого конфига.

```
Db::connect('mainDb')->query($sql)->fetchAll();
```

И третий вариант это когда вы в конструктор передаёте параметры подключения, но нужно подумать как потом пробрасывать этот экземпляр во все модули остальные, чтоб из них можно было достучатся до базы. Не использовать же **$db** как global переменную. Можно конечно создать некий **$application** который будет хранить все компоненты и передавать его во все модули. Но мне такой подход не нравится. Лично я использовал статику для верхнего уровня, а у неё уже компоненты в виде экземпляров. Нравится то как это сделано в Yii2 через пайпинг

```
Yii::$app->db->query($sql)->fetchAll();
```